# How do I access my system code that is in the app engine through the cloud shell?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-shell

I have a system on App Engine, but I need to upload an HTML file in the code. How do I access my system folder through Cloud Shell and upload the HTML file?

Comment: Why not just redeploy with the latest code? The deployment process might be doing things like moving the static files to frontend servers, so you don't want to directly update them.

Comment: I didn't want to risk tampering with files that are working correctly in the app engine.
If I redeployed the entire system, I could be at risk of error.

Comment: It wasn't me who developed this system, so there are a lot of bugs can't fix right now.
I tried to fix and gave numerous errors, so I do not want to mess with what is already working.

Comment: If you mess something you can go back to previous version

Comment: Can you share an screenshot of the error's you are getting and what kind of App Engine you are using?

Answer (score 1):

You can not upload a single file to Google App Engine. When you deploy to GAE, the process syncs your local files (working directory) with the remote files (remote directory). All changes made on the working directory will be reflected on the remote directory after deployment.

Answer (score 0):

As marian suggest you will need to try deploying your application again including all the files you want to be uploaded(such the html file you mentioned).

You can check this document [1]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/intellij/deploy-flex